# Order of operations with matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm confused with right/left multiplication with matrices. Say I have $B = S^{-1}AS$, where $S$ and $A$ are invertible. If I wanted to get $I$ on the right side of the equation, why do I have to do it like $B(S^{-1}A^{-1}S) = (S^{-1}AS)(S^{-1}A^{-1}S)$?

Why does this work? Why can't I multiply from the left? My professor never really explained order of operations.

Comment: You can multiply from the left. You would get (S^-1A^-1S)B = (S^-1A^-1S)(S^-1AS)=...=I

Comment: In general, $AB \neq BA$, but if $A$ is the inverse of $B$, then $AB = BA = I$, i.e. you can multiply on either the right or the left to get $I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is associative but not commutative.

If $B = S^{-1}AS$ and $B$ is invertible then you can show $B^{-1} = S^{-1}A^{-1}S$

since  $(S^{-1}A^{-1}S)(S^{-1}AS) = S^{-1}(A^{-1}(SS^{-1})A)S = S^{-1}(A^{-1}A)S = S^{-1}S = I$

and similarly $(S^{-1}AS)(S^{-1}A^{-1}S) = S^{-1}(A(SS^{-1})A^{-1})S = S^{-1}(AA^{-1})S = S^{-1}S = I$

More generally in multiplication of invertible square matrices, you have $(CD)^{-1} = D^{-1}C^{-1}$ and you can prove this the same way

Answer (score 0):

For this, 
you can multiply
on the left or right.
The main thing to realize
is that,
for square matrices,
a left inverse is a right inverse
and vice versa,
so
$SS^{-1} = S^{-1}S =I$.

Therefore
we have the following chains.

$\begin{array}\\
B
&=S^{-1}AS\\
SB
&=SS^{-1}AS\\
&=IAS\\
&=AS\\
SBS^{-1}
&=ASS^{-1}\\
&=A\\
\text{and}\\
B
&=S^{-1}AS\\
BS^{-1}
&=S^{-1}ASS^{-1}\\
&=S^{-1}A\\
&=AS\\
SBS^{-1}
&=ASS^{-1}\\
&=A\\
\end{array}
$